# Codility Invalid result type, int expected with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Could you tell why Codility tell me the next error, please?

> Running solution... Compilation successful.
>
> Example test:    [-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1]  Output (stderr): Invalid
>   result type, int expected. RUNTIME ERROR  (tested program terminated
>   unexpectedly)
>
> Detected some errors.

My solution was wrote on PHP.

```
function solution($A) {
    $N = count($A);
    $Ps = array();
    foreach ( $A  as $KeyP => $P ) {
        $sum = 0;
        if ( $KeyP == 0 ) {                 
            for ( $x = 1; $x < $N; $x++ ) {
                $sum += $A[$x];
            }
            if ( $sum == $P ) {
                $Ps[] = $KeyP;
            }
        }
        else {
            if ( ($KeyP+1) == $N ) {                
                for ( $z = 0; $z < $KeyP; $z++) :
                    $sum += $A[$z];
                endfor;     
                if ( ( $sum >= 0 ) AND ( $sum  < $N ) ) {
                    $Ps[] = $KeyP;
                }   
            }           
            else {      
                $sum1 = 0;
                $sum2 = 0;          
                for ( $z = 0; $z < $KeyP; $z++ ) :
                    $sum1 += $A[$z];
                endfor; 
                for ( $y = ( $KeyP+1 ); $y <= ($N-1); $y++ ) :
                    $sum2 += $A[$y];
                endfor;                             
                if ( $sum1 == $sum2 ) {
                    if ( $sum1 < $N ) {
                        $Ps[] = $KeyP;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    return ( count($Ps) <= 0 ) ? -1: $Ps;
}
```

The output of my function given the next array has been:

```
array(-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1);
```

Ouput

> Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 7 )

It's just like they request me in the task but Codility show me all those errors.

The demo task is below:

> This is a demo task.
>
> A zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. An
>   equilibrium index of this array is any integer P such that 0 ≤ P < N
>   and the sum of elements of lower indices is equal to the sum of
>   elements of higher indices, i.e.  A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[P−1] = A[P+1]
>   + ... + A[N−2] + A[N−1]. Sum of zero elements is assumed to be equal to 0. This can happen if P = 0 or if P = N−1.
>
> For example, consider the following array A consisting of N = 8
>   elements:
>
> ```
> A[0] => -1   
> A[1] =>  3 
> A[2] => -4   
> A[3] =>  5   
> A[4] =>  1   
> A[5] => -6   
> A[6] =>  2   
> A[7] =>  1
> ```
>
> P = 1 is an equilibrium index of this array, because:
>
> A[0] = −1 = A[2] + A[3] + A[4] + A[5] + A[6] + A[7] P = 3 is an
>   equilibrium index of this array, because:
>
> A[0] + A[1] + A[2] = −2 = A[4] + A[5] + A[6] + A[7] P = 7 is also an
>   equilibrium index, because:
>
> A[0] + A[1] + A[2] + A[3] + A[4] + A[5] + A[6] = 0 and there are no
>   elements with indices greater than 7.
>
> P = 8 is not an equilibrium index, because it does not fulfill the
>   condition 0 ≤ P < N.
>
> Write a function:
>
> function solution($A);
>
> that, given a zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers, returns
>   any of its equilibrium indices. The function should return −1 if no
>   equilibrium index exists.
>
> For example, given array A shown above, the function may return 1, 3
>   or 7, as explained above.
>
> Assume that:
>
> N is an integer within the range [0..100,000]; each element of array A
>   is an integer within the range [−2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647].
>   Complexity:
>
> expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected worst-case space
>   complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage
>   required for input arguments). Elements of input arrays can be
>   modified.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

for the Codility error please check this post : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19804284/4369087

Try this one it's more readable, in this solution I'm making the code more readable by introducing two functions.
`sumRight()`, `sumLeft()` in which I use built in php functions.

> [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)  : Calculate the sum of values in an array : 
>   it returns the sum of values as an integer or float; 0 if the array is empty.
>
> [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php): Extract a slice of the array: array_slice() returns
>   the sequence of elements from the array as specified by the
>   offset and length parameters.

So every time we loop over the array we calculate to sum of the right and left slice of the array from the given position `$i` :

```
<?php

function solution(array $a)
{
    $result = [];

    $count = count($a);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if(sumLeft($a, $i-1) === sumRight($a, $i+1)) {
            $result[] = $i;
        }
    }

    return  count($result) ? $result : -1;
}

function sumRight(array $a, float $position): float
{
    return array_sum(array_slice($a, $position));;
}

function sumLeft(array $a, float $position): float
{
    return array_sum(array_slice($a, 0, $position + 1));
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(solution([-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1]));
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 7
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the fact that your code could be more easy to read than mine doesn't mean that Codility will approve it. In fact, the solution and the output is the same, so, both codes are giving the same error. :( Greetings.

Comment: you're welcome @FernandoUrban, which php version gives the errors ?

Comment: In Codility wants PHP7.

Comment: how about some type hints, i changed my code, could you please try it again

Comment: Change `$i = 0; $count = count($a),` to `$i = 0, $count = count($a);` so that it is cached and not called on each iteration.  Just a matter of swapping the semicolon and the comma.  And when you iron out an answer for the OP, please include an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The Tape Equilibrium questions is worded super confusingly.

- P is the values of the array $A
- P values must be greater than 0 and less than N
- N is the total number of indexes in the array $A
- $A is a non-empty array consisting of N integers

The part "0 < P < N" doesn't make sense. If N is the integers in non-empty array A then N should be the length of the array and data such as [100,200] should not work because P=100 & P=200, both of which are greater than 2.

My opinion is that the explanation is poorly worded. However, the example is clear, so the solution is relatively straight forward if you can get past the opening text.

> A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given. Array A represents numbers on a tape.
> Any integer P, such that 0 < P < N, splits this tape into two
> non-empty parts: A[0], A[1], ..., A[P − 1] and A[P], A[P + 1], ...,
> A[N − 1].
>
> The difference between the two parts is the value of: |(A[0] + A[1] +
> ... + A[P − 1]) − (A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[N − 1])|
>
> In other words, it is the absolute difference between the sum of the
> first part and the sum of the second part.

The part that stumped me initially was that I was returning NULL for erroneous array input and receiving a Codility error that NULL was returned when it was expecting an INT. I thought, how can I return an INT when there is no solution for bad data? Turns out, they want you to return a zero.

**Here is my 100/100 PHP solution:**

```
function solution($A) {
    if ( empty($A) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    $count = count($A);
    
    if ($count == 1) {
        return $A[0];
    }
    
    for ($i=0, $max_position = $count - 1; $i<$max_position; $i++) {
        if (!is_int($A[$i])) {
            return;
        }

        if ($i == 0) {
            $left = $A[0];
            $right = array_sum($A) - $left;
        
            $min = abs($left - $right);
        }
        else {
            $left += $A[$i];
            $right -= $A[$i];

            $min = min([$min, abs($left - $right)]);   
        }
    }

    return $min;
}
```

Three things to take note of.

1. IF $A is empty then return an integer (0) because NULL results in a
   codility error
2. If $A only has one index then return an integer (0) because you cannot split a single index into two equal parts like they want and
   NULL results in a codility error
3. Apparently, invalid non-integer values are not tested - you can see where I checked for !is_int($A[$i]) and then a "return;" that
   should have resulted in a NULL (and an error about the NULL not
   being an int), but I did not.

Answer (score 0):

> Assume that: N is an integer within the range [0..100,000]; each element of array A is an integer within the range [−2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647].

This means I don't see any reason to check if an element `isInt()` as suggested by @Floyd.

For best efficiency, always break/return as early as possible.

There is no reason to iterate on the first or last index in the array because splitting the array on the first element will result in nothing on the "left side" and splitting on the last element will result in nothing on the "right side".  For this reason, start iterating from `1` and only iterate while `$i` is less than array count - 1.

I struggled to follow the asker's coding attempt, but it seems likely that iterating/evaluating the bookend elements was to blame.

Code -- not actually tested on Codility: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hPbrk))

```
$test =  [-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1];

function solution(array $array): int {
    for ($i = 1, $count = count($array) - 1; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        if (array_sum(array_slice($array, 0, $i)) === array_sum(array_slice($array, $i + 1))) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
echo solution($test);
```